# AAB not uploaded to Play Store internal track

Tags: flutter, fastlane

I am wondering what I have to do, so the aab is automatically uploaded to Google Play Store internal track when using fastlane?
This is my lane for android beta:

```
lane :beta do
    gradle(
        task: 'clean bundle',
        build_type: 'Release',
        properties: {
            "android.injected.version.code" => 7,
            "android.injected.version.name" => "1.0.1",
        }
    )
    upload_to_play_store(track: "internal", skip_upload_changelogs: true, skip_upload_metadata: true, skip_upload_screenshots: true)

end
```